# How to insert string from model into <a href="mailto: /> link?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

In `@model.Author.UserName` I keep valid e mail address.

I wanted to insert it in html `<a href="" />` link.

I tried that and few variations of:

```
<a href="mailto:@model.Author.UserName />
```

with brackets in few places but there are still syntax errors.

How to insert string from model into `<a href="mailto: />` link?

Answer (score 1):

What you have will work but need the ending double quote and a capital "M" in C# (VB is OK without).  Razor is very picky about syntax, and it has to be exactly right for parsing to work.

```
<a href="mailto:@Model.Author.UserName">Content</a>
```

or try:

```
<a href="mailto:@(Model.Author.UserName)">Content</a>
```

Comment: Here I get `Error 1 The name 'model' does not exist in the current context` but it does I have lot of references to it above.

Comment: small capital works in other helpers fine but I post te solution don't know why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
<a href='mailto:@Model.Author.UserName'>Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<a href="mailto:@Model.Author.UserName">@Model.Author.UserName</a>
```

and I don't know why this not:

```
<a href="mailto:@Model.Author.UserName"/>
```

I think it just should give the same output.

Comment: Yeah sorry, don't know why I didn't see that before; the inner HTML is not automatically taken from the HREF.  A link needs content defined explicitly.